# MySQL Join two selects with same ID

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL table:

```
GAME

ID     PLAYER     MIN_VALUE_1  MIN_VALUE_2
1      John       1.2          3
2      Paul       1.4          3.2
3      Henry      1.6          3.4
4      Tom        2.1          3.6

PREDICTIONS

ID_GAME     HOUSE       VALUE_1   VALUE_2    
1           house_a     1.5       3
1           house_b     1         2.9
2           house_a     1.2       3.1
2           house_b     1.4       3.6
2           house_c     1.5       4
3           house_a     1.5       4
3           house_b     1.7       4.2
3           house_c     1.8       4
3           house_d     1.9       4.3
4           house_b     1.6       3.1
4           house_d     1.9       3
```

I have two selects:

With this:

```
SELECT *                  
FROM game m
INNER JOIN predictions p ON m.id = p.id_game
WHERE p.value_1 >= m.min_value_1 OR p.value_2 >= m.min_value_2
```

I get all rows with VALUE_1 >= MIN_VALUE_1 or VALUE_2 >= MIN_VALUE_2

```
ID_GAME     HOUSE       VALUE_1   VALUE_2    MIN_VALUE_1   MIN_VALUE_2
1           house_a     1.5       3          1.2          3
2           house_b     1.4       3.6        1.4          3.2
2           house_c     1.5       4          1.4          3.2
3           house_a     1.5       4          1.6          3.4
3           house_b     1.7       4.2        1.6          3.4
3           house_c     1.8       4          1.6          3.4
3           house_d     1.9       4.3        1.6          3.4
```

And with query:

```
SELECT *                  
FROM game m
INNER JOIN predictions p ON m.id = p.id_game
WHERE p.value_1 < m.min_value_1 AND p.value_2 < m.min_value_2
```

I get all rows with VALUE_1 < MIN_VALUE_1 and VALUE_2 < MIN_VALUE_2

```
ID_GAME     HOUSE       VALUE_1   VALUE_2    MIN_VALUE_1   MIN_VALUE_2

1           house_b     1         2.9        1.2          3
2           house_a     1.2       3.1        1.4          3.2    
4           house_b     1.6       3.1        2.1          3.6
4           house_d     1.9       3          2.1          3.6
```

But I need to get all rows of the two queries but with **same ID_GAME**. I'll need this:

```
ID_GAME     HOUSE       VALUE_1   VALUE_2    MIN_VALUE_1   MIN_VALUE_2
1           house_a     1.5       3          1.2          3
1           house_b     1         2.9        1.2          3
2           house_a     1.2       3.1        1.4          3.2    
2           house_b     1.4       3.6        1.4          3.2
2           house_c     1.5       4          1.4          3.2
3           house_a     1.5       4          1.6          3.4
3           house_b     1.7       4.2        1.6          3.4
3           house_c     1.8       4          1.6          3.4
3           house_d     1.9       4.3        1.6          3.4
```

Comment: I must have missed something obvious... Can't you simply remove the `where`-clause if you want all items? (might need coffee)

Comment: I want all items with WHERE condition and with same ID_GAME

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove `where` clause

```
select * from predictions p INNER JOIN game m ON p.id_game = m.id WHERE  
p.value_1 < m.min_value_1 AND p.value_2 < m.min_value_2;
```

Comment: The WHERE condition is necessary, I updated the example.

Comment: @kurtko You are changing your post constantly, what you need now?

Comment: I've update the example because there was an error in values, but sql queries are the same

Comment: @kurtko you have changed table game..when i was created that table there were no min_val1 and min_val2 column..now i am trying again..please leave the tables as it now?

Comment: if you need result like above you mentioned then why would you need where clause in query

Comment: With your last answers I get the same that: SELECT *                  
FROM game m
INNER JOIN predictions p ON m.id = p.id_game
WHERE p.value_1 < m.min_value_1 AND p.value_2 < m.min_value_2

Comment: I need something like UNION ALL but only with same ID_GAME

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution (I don't know if ideal solution):

```
SELECT *                  
FROM game m
INNER JOIN predictions p ON m.id = p.id_game
AND m.id IN (
 SELECT m.id                  
 FROM game m
 INNER JOIN predictions p ON m.id = p.id_game
 WHERE p.value_1 >= m.min_value_1 OR p.value_2 >= m.min_value_2
)
```